# Why does get_post() not return anything?

Tags: hooks, actions, post-meta, get-post

Inside my functions.php I use `get_post()` or similar (such as `get_the_title()`) inside some of my functions.
It does not return anything. Why? And how to fix that?

P.S: And I can not really add `add_action('somehook', 'myfunc')`, because that makes things display in the wrong place.

Comment: It would be better if you show your code, I'm certain you then would get a even more on point answer. Not to take anything away from @jgraup's one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `$post` is null for [`get_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) it looks to `$GLOBALS['post']`.

There are several other checks in the [source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/#source) so perhaps you should find out the value of the global variable when you're calling it or give it something besides and empty value.

What does [`get_the_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) return vs. [`get_post(get_queried_object_id())`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/)? Or [`var_dump(get_queried_object())`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/)?

> [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) - Retrieves post data given a post ID or post object.
>
> [`get_queried_object()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) - Retrieve the currently-queried object. For example:
>
> - if you're on a single post, it will return the post object
> - if you're on a page, it will return the page object
> - if you're on an archive page, it will return the post type object
> - if you're on a category archive, it will return the category object
> - if you're on an author archive, it will return the author object
>     etc.

Comment: Hey, apparently get_queried_object() was what I was looking for, thanks a ton! :) It returns the post. Now i only need a proper explanation why this worked ^^